# Orion context broker: check subscription expiration?

Tags: c#, fiware, fiware-orion

Is there any way to check if the orion subscription (attribute subscription, not context availability subscription) is currently active or expired? Something similar to `discoverContextAvailability` for context information.

Example use case:

- I add a sensor device inside my application
- Register a context and a subscription for that device on Orion
- From that point subscription is running and returning sensor data to my application periodically
- Now, when the subscription expires the data simply stops coming

What is the recommended way to extend this subscription?
How can you know that it has expired in the first place?

The only way I see it is to store the expiration date in my app after creating the subscription, and run a scheduled task to extend it on that date.

Another way is to extend all subscriptions in fixed intervals (for example: make all subscriptions run for 2 months, and every month run the extension task).

The best and easiest way would be to register subscriptions without duration (unlimited duration) but I don't see that option anywhere in the documentation.

A similar problem exists with context registrations too, but I resolved it using the `discoverContextAvailability` method. Before each `queryContext` or `updateContext` I check if the context is expired with `discoverContextAvailability`. If it is I register it again and continue with query or update requests.

I know there is `subscribeContextAvailability`but it has the same problem like attribute subscriptions. Once it expires how do you know it has expired and how do you extend it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding checking expired subscriptions, that's not possible in NGSIv1, but it is planned for [NGSIv2](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/). The new `expires` and `status` subscription properties will allow to perform queries likes the following ones:

```
GET /v2/subscriptions?q=status==active
GET /v2/subscriptions?q=expires<2015-10-07T10:12:00
```

Regarding extending subscriptions (in NGSIv1), both ways you mention (store expiration date in your application or extend all subscriptions at regular intervals) are fine. I would say that the last one is the most common pattern.

Regarding subscriptions without expiration time (i.e. permantent subscriptions), NGSIv1 doesn't allow it (that will be fixed in NGSIv2: if a subscription doesn't include the `expires` field, then it is considered permanent). However, create the subscription with an absurdly large duration (e.g. 100 years) will work.

Availability subscriptions work pretty much the same regarding these aspects.